# How to group row values in column and converting rows into column?

Tags: sql

My requirment is as follows: using Sql query in sql 2005, if possible want to avoid stored procedure.

```
EmpType  EmpName         Role

1             Ram        Admin

2             Raja       Admin

1             John       update

2             Tom        Admin

1             Adam       Admin
```

I need a output in group by EmpType like this:

```
EmpType        EmpName           Admin      Update

1              Ram, John, Adam   Adam,Ram    John

2              Raja , Tom        Tom,Raja
```

Could anyone help me .

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

To perform the task you need to write your own aggregate function that concatinates strings. Here's an example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;

[Serializable]
[SqlUserDefinedAggregate(Format.UserDefined,  MaxByteSize=8000)]
public struct strconcat : IBinarySerialize{
        private List values;

        public void Init()    {
            this.values = new List();
        }

        public void Accumulate(SqlString value)    {
            this.values.Add(value.Value);
        }

        public void Merge(strconcat value)    {
            this.values.AddRange(value.values.ToArray());
        }

        public SqlString Terminate()    {
            return new SqlString(string.Join(", ", this.values.ToArray()));
        }

        public void Read(BinaryReader r)    {
            int itemCount = r.ReadInt32();
            this.values = new List(itemCount);
            for (int i = 0; i <= itemCount - 1; i++)    {
                this.values.Add(r.ReadString());
            }
        }



        public void Write(BinaryWriter w)    {
            w.Write(this.values.Count);
            foreach (string s in this.values)      {
                w.Write(s);
            }
        }
}
```

That the query will be:

```
SELECT * FROM
(Select EmpType, EmpName, Role
FROM TableName) t
PIVOT
(
   dbo.strconcat(EmpName) FOR Role IN ([Admin], [update])
) p
```

You might also want to check [this link](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to create extra structure (stored procedures, functions, etc.) this is what you're looking for:

```
select 
    EmpType, 
    stuff((select ', ' + EmpName from tmp t2 where t2.EmpType = t1.EmpType 
           for xml path('')),1,2,'') EmpName,
    stuff((select ', ' + EmpName from tmp t2 where t2.EmpType = t1.EmpType and t2.Role = 'Admin' 
           for xml path('')),1,2,'') [Admin],
    stuff((select ', ' + EmpName from tmp t2 where t2.EmpType = t1.EmpType and t2.Role = 'Update' 
           for xml path('')),1,2,'') [Update]
from tmp t1
group by EmpType
```

Comment: Did this help you at all? Let us know.